# Pegar um objeto de dentro de uma array e enviá-lo para outra array?

Tags: javascript, array

Estou precisando tirar um objeto de dentro de uma array e enviar esse mesmo objeto para outra array. Vejam:

```js
todasAsCartas:[
            { id: 1, valor: 2, naipe: 'Paus'   },  { id: 2, valor: 2, naipe: 'Copas'   },  { id: 3, valor: 3, naipe: 'Espadas'   },  { id: 4, valor: 2, naipe: 'Ouros'   },
            { id: 5, valor: 3, naipe: 'Paus'   },  { id: 6, valor: 3, naipe: 'Copas'   },  { id: 7, valor: 3, naipe: 'Espadas'   },  { id: 8, valor: 3, naipe: 'Ouros'   },
            { id: 9, valor: 4, naipe: 'Paus'   },  { id: 10, valor: 4, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 11, valor: 4, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 12, valor: 4, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 13, valor: 5, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 14, valor: 5, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 15, valor: 5, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 16, valor: 5, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 17, valor: 6, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 18, valor: 6, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 19, valor: 6, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 20, valor: 6, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 21, valor: 7, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 22, valor: 7, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 23, valor: 7, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 24, valor: 7, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 25, valor: 8, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 26, valor: 8, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 27, valor: 8, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 28, valor: 8, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 29, valor: 9, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 30, valor: 9, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 31, valor: 9, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 32, valor: 9, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 33, valor: 10, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 34, valor: 10, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 35, valor: 10, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 36, valor: 10, naipe: 'Ouros' },
            { id: 37, valor: 11, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 38, valor: 11, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 39, valor: 11, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 40, valor: 11, naipe: 'Ouros' },
            { id: 41, valor: 12, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 42, valor: 12, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 43, valor: 12, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 44, valor: 12, naipe: 'Ouros' },
            { id: 45, valor: 13, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 46, valor: 13, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 47, valor: 13, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 48, valor: 13, naipe: 'Ouros' },
            { id: 49, valor: 14, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 50, valor: 14, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 51, valor: 14, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 52, valor: 14, naipe: 'Ouros' },
            
        ]
```

Preciso tirar um desses objetos dessa array "todasAsCartas: [ ]" e mandar pra outra array de forma aleatória (randomicamente), por exemplo para a array "cartasNaMao: [ ]"...

Alguém faz ideia de como resolve isso no JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

```js
let cartasNaMesa = [
  { id: 1, valor: 2, naipe: 'Paus'   },  { id: 2, valor: 2, naipe: 'Copas'   },  { id: 3, valor: 3, naipe: 'Espadas'   },  { id: 4, valor: 2, naipe: 'Ouros'   },
  { id: 5, valor: 3, naipe: 'Paus'   },  { id: 6, valor: 3, naipe: 'Copas'   },  { id: 7, valor: 3, naipe: 'Espadas'   },  { id: 8, valor: 3, naipe: 'Ouros'   },
  { id: 9, valor: 4, naipe: 'Paus'   },  { id: 10, valor: 4, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 11, valor: 4, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 12, valor: 4, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
  { id: 13, valor: 5, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 14, valor: 5, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 15, valor: 5, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 16, valor: 5, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
  { id: 17, valor: 6, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 18, valor: 6, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 19, valor: 6, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 20, valor: 6, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
  { id: 21, valor: 7, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 22, valor: 7, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 23, valor: 7, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 24, valor: 7, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
  { id: 25, valor: 8, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 26, valor: 8, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 27, valor: 8, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 28, valor: 8, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
  { id: 29, valor: 9, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 30, valor: 9, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 31, valor: 9, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 32, valor: 9, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
  { id: 33, valor: 10, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 34, valor: 10, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 35, valor: 10, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 36, valor: 10, naipe: 'Ouros' },
  { id: 37, valor: 11, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 38, valor: 11, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 39, valor: 11, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 40, valor: 11, naipe: 'Ouros' },
  { id: 41, valor: 12, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 42, valor: 12, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 43, valor: 12, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 44, valor: 12, naipe: 'Ouros' },
  { id: 45, valor: 13, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 46, valor: 13, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 47, valor: 13, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 48, valor: 13, naipe: 'Ouros' },
  { id: 49, valor: 14, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 50, valor: 14, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 51, valor: 14, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 52, valor: 14, naipe: 'Ouros' },
];

let cartasNaMao = [];

const cartasParaComprar = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < cartasParaComprar; i++) {
  const numeroAleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * cartasNaMesa.length);
  const cartaAleatoria = cartasNaMesa[numeroAleatorio];

  // Remove a carta aleatória da mesa
  cartasNaMesa = cartasNaMesa.filter(carta => carta.id !== cartaAleatoria.id);

  // E coloca ela na mão
  cartasNaMao.push(cartaAleatoria);
}

console.log('Cartas na mesa:\n', cartasNaMesa);
console.log('Cartas na mão:\n', cartasNaMao);
```

Comment: Excelente @MichaelPacheco!

Comment: Cara, é isso aí.. Faltou apenas um "const carta = 0" no começo ali antes do for. Funcionou aqui. Show de bola. Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. Não há necessidade de um `const carta = 0` fora do `for`. A linha `const cartaAleatoria = cartasNaMesa[numeroAleatorio];` já resolve o problema :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.push()` e `.splice()` depois de gerar um número aleatório até o tamanho da array principal:

```js
var cartasNaMao = [];
var todasAsCartas =[
   { id: 1, valor: 2, naipe: 'Paus'   },  { id: 2, valor: 2, naipe: 'Copas'   },  { id: 3, valor: 3, naipe: 'Espadas'   },  { id: 4, valor: 2, naipe: 'Ouros'   },
   { id: 5, valor: 3, naipe: 'Paus'   },  { id: 6, valor: 3, naipe: 'Copas'   },  { id: 7, valor: 3, naipe: 'Espadas'   },  { id: 8, valor: 3, naipe: 'Ouros'   },
   { id: 9, valor: 4, naipe: 'Paus'   },  { id: 10, valor: 4, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 11, valor: 4, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 12, valor: 4, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
   { id: 13, valor: 5, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 14, valor: 5, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 15, valor: 5, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 16, valor: 5, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
   { id: 17, valor: 6, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 18, valor: 6, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 19, valor: 6, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 20, valor: 6, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
   { id: 21, valor: 7, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 22, valor: 7, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 23, valor: 7, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 24, valor: 7, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
   { id: 25, valor: 8, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 26, valor: 8, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 27, valor: 8, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 28, valor: 8, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
   { id: 29, valor: 9, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 30, valor: 9, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 31, valor: 9, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 32, valor: 9, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
   { id: 33, valor: 10, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 34, valor: 10, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 35, valor: 10, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 36, valor: 10, naipe: 'Ouros' },
   { id: 37, valor: 11, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 38, valor: 11, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 39, valor: 11, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 40, valor: 11, naipe: 'Ouros' },
   { id: 41, valor: 12, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 42, valor: 12, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 43, valor: 12, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 44, valor: 12, naipe: 'Ouros' },
   { id: 45, valor: 13, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 46, valor: 13, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 47, valor: 13, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 48, valor: 13, naipe: 'Ouros' },
   { id: 49, valor: 14, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 50, valor: 14, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 51, valor: 14, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 52, valor: 14, naipe: 'Ouros' },
];

var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * todasAsCartas.length); // nº randômico dentro do range da array principal
cartasNaMao.push(todasAsCartas[rand]); // insere o obj randômico na segunda array
todasAsCartas.splice(rand,1); // remove o obj da array principal

console.log("Na mão: ",cartasNaMao, "Todas: ",todasAsCartas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro passo é definir o número aleatório com base no número de cartas.
Depois, basta percorrer a listagem e salvar esse valor, além de remover esse valor da lista atual.

É possível utilizar o **filter** para procurar dentro da listagem de cartas uma carta específica.

E para remover pode-se usar o **splice(index, 1)** na listagem.

```js
let cartasNaMesa = [
  { id: 1, valor: 2, naipe: 'Paus'   },  { id: 2, valor: 2, naipe: 'Copas'   },  { id: 3, valor: 3, naipe: 'Espadas'   },  { id: 4, valor: 2, naipe: 'Ouros'   },
  { id: 5, valor: 3, naipe: 'Paus'   },  { id: 6, valor: 3, naipe: 'Copas'   },  { id: 7, valor: 3, naipe: 'Espadas'   },  { id: 8, valor: 3, naipe: 'Ouros'   },
  { id: 9, valor: 4, naipe: 'Paus'   },  { id: 10, valor: 4, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 11, valor: 4, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 12, valor: 4, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
  { id: 13, valor: 5, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 14, valor: 5, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 15, valor: 5, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 16, valor: 5, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
  { id: 17, valor: 6, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 18, valor: 6, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 19, valor: 6, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 20, valor: 6, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
  { id: 21, valor: 7, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 22, valor: 7, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 23, valor: 7, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 24, valor: 7, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
  { id: 25, valor: 8, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 26, valor: 8, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 27, valor: 8, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 28, valor: 8, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
  { id: 29, valor: 9, naipe: 'Paus'  },  { id: 30, valor: 9, naipe: 'Copas'  },  { id: 31, valor: 9, naipe: 'Espadas'  },  { id: 32, valor: 9, naipe: 'Ouros'  },
  { id: 33, valor: 10, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 34, valor: 10, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 35, valor: 10, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 36, valor: 10, naipe: 'Ouros' },
  { id: 37, valor: 11, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 38, valor: 11, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 39, valor: 11, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 40, valor: 11, naipe: 'Ouros' },
  { id: 41, valor: 12, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 42, valor: 12, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 43, valor: 12, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 44, valor: 12, naipe: 'Ouros' },
  { id: 45, valor: 13, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 46, valor: 13, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 47, valor: 13, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 48, valor: 13, naipe: 'Ouros' },
  { id: 49, valor: 14, naipe: 'Paus' },  { id: 50, valor: 14, naipe: 'Copas' },  { id: 51, valor: 14, naipe: 'Espadas' },  { id: 52, valor: 14, naipe: 'Ouros' },
];

//gera um número aleatório com base na quantidade de cartas
const randomNumero = Math.floor(Math.random() * cartasNaMesa.length);

//Percorre a lista de cartas na mesa e salva na variavel castasNaMao apenas a carta aleatória.
const cartasNaMao = cartasNaMesa.filter(function(val, index){

  const cartaAleatoria = cartasNaMesa[randomNumero];

  if(cartaAleatoria.id === val.id){      
      cartasNaMesa.splice(index, 1 );
      return true;
  }
})

console.log('Cartas na mesa:\n', cartasNaMesa);
console.log('Cartas na mão:\n', cartasNaMao);
```